# What's the correct way to initialize a member array with an initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `struct` that holds an array, and I'd like to pass an initializer list to the struct's constructor to be forwarded on to the array. To illustrate, I tried:

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct Vector
{
    float v[3];

    Vector(std::initializer_list<float> values) : v{values} {}
};

int main()
{
    Vector v = {1, 2, 3};
}
```

[Which resulted in the error](http://ideone.com/FfRRNp):

> `error: cannot convert ‘std::initializer_list<float>’ to ‘float’ in initialization`

[I tried using parentheses instead of braces](http://ideone.com/YMRVBY) for `v` but that gave the error:

> `error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘std::initializer_list<float>’ to ‘float [3]’`

My main motivation for trying to do this is to avoid the following warning that clang generates:

```
template <int N>
struct Vector
{
    float v[N];
};

template <>
struct Vector<2>
{
    float x, y;
};

int main()
{
    Vector<2> v2 = {1.0f, 2.0f};         // Yay, works
    Vector<3> v3 = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};   // Results in warning in clang++
    Vector<3> u3 = {{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f}}; // Must use two braces to avoid warning
    // If I could make Vector<N> take an initializer list in its constructor, I
    // could forward that on to the member array and avoid using the double braces
}
```

> `warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject`

So my question is: **How can I initialize a member array with an initializer list? (i.e. How can I make the first code work?** Or is it not possible?

Comment: For an aggregate, you wouldn't even need a ctor. Note the size of an `initializer_list` is variable. There's also a difference between initializing with an `initializer-list` and _list-initialization_ (which is a language construct and may lead to calling a ctor using an initializer-list).

Comment: You can't really do it, but could you use an `std::array` instead?

Comment: He could use std::array, but I read this as a question about the language, not the standard library. And, with due respect to whomever, telling someone to go read the standard library is like telling a toddler to learn English by reading Shakespeare. So std::array isn't a very good answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your class is an [aggregate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), you can use your syntax

```
template < std::size_t len >
struct Vector
{
    float elems[len];
};

Vector<3> v = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
```

Note: this is possible due to brace-elision. No need for `v = {{1,2,3}};` though this is also possible. Clang issues this warning because the clearer and less error-prone syntax is with the double braces (one for initializing `v` and one for initializing the sub-aggregate `elems`).

If your class is not an aggregate, you can use variadic templates:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template < std::size_t len >
struct Vector
{
    std::array < float, len > m;  // also works with raw array `float m[len];`

    template < typename... TT >
    Vector(TT... pp) : m{{pp...}}
    {}

    // better, using perfect forwarding:
    // template < typename... TT >
    // Vector(TT&&... pp) : m{{std::forward<TT>(pp)...}}
    // {}
};

Vector<3> a = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
```

Answer (score 12):

Plain C style arrays are not assignable. If you switch over to using `std::array` instead, the initialization becomes trivial.

```
#include <array>

struct Vector
{
    std::array<float, 3> v;

    Vector(std::array<float, 3> const& values) 
    : v(values)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Vector v{{1, 2, 3}};
}
```

Comment: +1 for recommending `std::array`. It allows much better syntax for initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `std::copy`.

```
Vector(std::initializer_list<float> values) 
{
    std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), v);
}
```

Comment: What if the list is bigger than v's capacity?

Answer (score 0):

To initialize an array non-static member, use the aggregate syntax.  That is, directly fill the braced-list with `N` elements, where *N* is the number of elements in the array.  You can use fewer than *N* if the element type is Default-Constructible; the missing elements will be value-initialized.

There is no conversion from a `std::initializer_list` to an array.  Even if you were using a source type that could convert to an array reference (never a value), you couldn't exploit the conversion in a member initializer since arrays are not Assignable.  In these cases, you have to use something like `std::copy` within the constructor's body.

Note for multidimensional arrays, since arrays aren't Assignable, you only use braced-lists to represent the sub-arrays.  There is also the option of brace elision; using a flat list of `std::remove_all_extents<TheArrayType>::type` items and the compiler will make-do.  (When the inner non-array type is a built-in character type, you can sometimes use a quoted string as the next-to-innermost initializer for a multidimensional array.)