# Array declaration and initialization in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++14, stdarray

Here are 8 ways to declare and initialize arrays in C++11 that seems ok under `g++`:

```
/*0*/ std::array<int, 3> arr0({1, 2, 3});
/*1*/ std::array<int, 3> arr1({{1, 2, 3}});
/*2*/ std::array<int, 3> arr2{1, 2, 3};
/*3*/ std::array<int, 3> arr3{{1, 2, 3}};
/*4*/ std::array<int, 3> arr4 = {1, 2, 3};
/*5*/ std::array<int, 3> arr5 = {{1, 2, 3}};
/*6*/ std::array<int, 3> arr6 = std::array<int, 3>({1, 2, 3});
/*7*/ std::array<int, 3> arr7 = std::array<int, 3>({{1, 2, 3}});
```

What are the correct ones according to the strict standard (and the upcoming C++14 standard) ?
What are the most common/used and those to avoid (and for what reason) ?

Comment: When asking g++, do it with `-Wall -pedantic`. Do the same for Clang, this helps a lot. For example arr 4 is missing the second pair of {}.

Comment: First, I wondered why `arr0` and `arr1` even work; do they call the move-ctor? If so, they have a different meaning than 2-5 (similar to 6 and 7).

Comment: Why the rollback? The version numbers were useful and didn't distract.

Comment: @dudeprgm the top answer says "examples 0,2,6 are not required to work". However it is not clear from your numbering which lines those are.  Without your edit I would assume "example 0" means `arr0`  so your numbering has added confusion (to me anyway)

Comment: @MattMcNabb ...oops, sorry, I rolled back to an earlier revision of someone that had the numbers starting at "example 1", not "example 0". Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C++11 summary / TL;DR

- Due to the brace elision defect, examples 0, 2, 6 are not required to work. Recent version of compilers however implement the proposed resolution for that defect, so that these examples will work.
- As it is unspecified whether `std::array` contains a raw array. Therefore, examples 1, 3, 5, 7 are not required to work. However, I do not know of a Standard Library implementation where they do not work (in practice).
- Example 4 will always work: `std::array<int, 3> arr4 = {1, 2, 3};`

I'd prefer version 4 or version 2 (with the brace elision fix), since they initialize directly and are required/likely to work.

For Sutter's AAA style, you can use `auto arrAAA = std::array<int, 3>{1, 2, 3};`, but this requires the brace elision fix.

---

`std::array` is required to be an aggregate [array.overview]/2, this implies it has no user-provided constructors (i.e. only default, copy, move ctor).

---

```
std::array<int, 3> arr0({1, 2, 3});
std::array<int, 3> arr1({{1, 2, 3}});
```

An initialization with `(..)` is direct-initialization. This requires a constructor call. In the case of `arr0` and `arr1`, only the copy/move constructor are viable. Therefore, those two examples mean *create a temporary `std::array` from the braced-init-list, and copy/move it to the destination*. Through copy/move elision, the compiler *is allowed to* elide that copy/move operation, even if it has side effects.

<sub>N.B. even though the temporaries are prvalues, it might invoke a copy (semantically, before copy elision) as the move ctor of `std::array` might not be implicitly declared, e.g. if it were deleted.</sub>

---

```
std::array<int, 3> arr6 = std::array<int, 3>({1, 2, 3});
std::array<int, 3> arr7 = std::array<int, 3>({{1, 2, 3}});
```

These are examples of copy-initialization. There are two temporaries created:

- through the braced-init-list `{1, 2, 3}` to call the copy/move constructor
- through the expression `std::array<int, 3>(..)`

the latter temporary then is copied/moved to the named destination variable. The creation of both temporaries can be elided.

<strike>As far as I know, an implementation could write an `explicit array(array const&) = default;` constructor and *not* violate the Standard; this would make those examples ill-formed.</strike> (This possibility is ruled out by [container.requirements.general], kudos to David Krauss, see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-discussion/bV65t0-e3X0/discussion).)

---

```
std::array<int, 3> arr2{1, 2, 3};
std::array<int, 3> arr3{{1, 2, 3}};
std::array<int, 3> arr4 = {1, 2, 3};
std::array<int, 3> arr5 = {{1, 2, 3}};
```

This is aggregate-initialization. They all "directly" initialize the `std::array`, without calling a constructor of `std::array` and without (semantically) creating a temporary array. The members of the `std::array` are initialized via copy-initialization (see below).

---

On the topic of brace-elision:

In the C++11 Standard, brace elision only applies to declarations of the form `T x = { a };` but not to `T x { a };`. This is [considered a defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1270) and will be fixed in C++1y, however the proposed resolution is not part of the Standard (DRWP status, see top of the linked page) and therefore you cannot count on your compiler implementing it also for `T x { a };`.

Therefore, `std::array<int, 3> arr2{1, 2, 3};` (examples 0, 2, 6) are ill-formed, strictly speaking. As far as I know, recent versions of clang++ and g++ allow the brace elision in `T x { a };` already.

<sub>In example 6, `std::array<int, 3>({1, 2, 3})` uses copy-initialization: the initialization for argument passing is also copy-init. The defective restriction of brace elision however, *"In a declaration of the form `T x = { a };`"*, also disallows brace elision for argument passing, since it's not a declaration and certainly not of that form.</sub>

---

On the topic of aggregate-initialization:

As [Johannes Schaub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) points out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519992/array-declaration-and-initialization-in-c11/20520717?noredirect=1#comment30863080_20520717), it is *only* guaranteed that you can initialize a `std::array` with the following syntax [array.overview]/2:

```
array<T, N> a = { initializer-list };
```

You can deduce from that, **if** brace-elision is allowed in the form `T x { a };`, that the syntax

```
array<T, N> a { initializer-list };
```

is well-formed and has the same meaning. However, it is not guaranteed that `std::array` actually contains a raw array as its only data member (also see [LWG 2310](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-active.html#2310)). I think one example could be a partial specialization `std::array<T, 2>`, where there are two data members `T m0` and `T m1`. Therefore, one cannot conclude that

```
array<T, N> a {{ initializer-list }};
```

is well-formed. This unfortunately leads to the situation that there's no guaranteed way of initializing a `std::array` temporary w/o brace elision for `T x { a };`, and also means that the odd examples (1, 3, 5, 7) are not required to work.

---

All of these ways to initialize a `std::array` eventually lead to aggregate-initialization. It is defined as copy-initialization of the aggregate members. However, copy-initialization using a braced-init-list can still directly initialize an aggregate member. For example:

```
struct foo { foo(int); foo(foo const&)=delete; };
std::array<foo, 2> arr0 = {1, 2};      // error: deleted copy-ctor
std::array<foo, 2> arr1 = {{1}, {2}};  // error/ill-formed, cannot initialize a
                                       // possible member array from {1}
                                       // (and too many initializers)
std::array<foo, 2> arr2 = {{{1}, {2}}}; // not guaranteed to work
```

The first tries to initialize the array elements from the initializer-clauses `1` and `2`, respectively. This copy-initialization is equivalent to `foo arr0_0 = 1;` which in turn is equivalent to `foo arr0_0 = foo(1);` which is illegal (deleted copy-ctor).

The second does not contain a list of expressions, but a list of initializers, therefore it doesn't fulfil the requirements of [array.overview]/2. In practice, `std::array` contains a raw array data member, which would be initialized (only) from the first initializer-clause `{1}`, the second clause `{2}` then is illegal.

The third has the opposite problem as the second: It works if there *is* an array data member, but that isn't guaranteed.

Comment: I would upvote if you would point out that examples 1, 3, 5 and 7 are not guaranteed to work aswell (because they rely on the internal aggregation structure/depth).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Umm.. yes.. that is bad. I restructured my answer and included my understanding of your comment (which leads to two unfortunate conclusions). Do you happen to know if there are any implementations that don't use a raw array member?

Answer (score 3):

I believe they are all strictly conforming, except possibly `arr2`. I would go with the `arr3` way, because it is concise, clear, and definitely valid. If `arr2` is valid (I'm just not sure), that would be even better, actually.

Combining parens and braces (0 and 1) never sits well with me, the equals (4 and 5) is ok, but I just prefer the shorter version, and 6 and 7 are just absurdly verbose.

However, you might want to go with yet another way, following [Herb Sutter's "almost always auto" style](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/):

```
auto arr8 = std::array<int, 3>{{1, 2, 3}};
```

Comment: I am writing a low level and highly templated library, so I avoid as much as possible the keyword "auto" because I need to keep track of types (but I agree that in most cases, it can be a solution).

Comment: "auto" used this way seems like writing Python code where the type of the declared variable is known by the assigned object. It's not too bad to use it in this example, but I prefer the third constructor of the initial post. I mostly use "auto" for iterators declared in loops.

Comment: @dyp 's answer appears to say that `std::array<int, 3>{{1, 2, 3}};` is not guaranteed to work because it is unspecified whether `std::array` uses a C-style array internally (and therefore `{1,2,3}` might not correctly initialize whatever it does use internally)

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13905432/1508519) links a [bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25137), in which `-Wmissing-braces` is no longer enabled by default when using `-Wall`. If you turn on `-Wmissing-braces`, `gcc` will complain about 0, 2, 4 and 6 (same as `clang`).

Brace elision is allowed to occur for statements in the form `T a = { ... }` but not `T a { }`.

[Why is the C++ initializer_list behavior for std::vector and std::array different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400090/c-why-initializer-list-behavior-for-stdvector-and-stdarray-are-different/11400125#11400125)

Here is [James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400125/1508519)'s answer:

> However, these extra braces may only be elided "in a declaration of
>   the form T x = { a };" (C++11 §8.5.1/11), that is, when the old style
>   = is used . This rule allowing brace elision does not apply for direct list initialization. A footnote here reads: "Braces cannot be elided
>   in other uses of list-initialization."
>
> There is a defect report concerning this restriction: CWG [defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1270)
>   #1270. If the proposed resolution is adopted, brace elision will be allowed for other forms of list initialization, ...
>
> If the proposed resolution is adopted, brace elision will be allowed
>   for other forms of list initialization, and the following will be
>   well-formed:
>   std::array y{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };

And [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400133/1508519)'s answer:

> ... while std::array has no constructors and the {1, 2, 3, 4} braced
>   init-list is in fact not interpreted as a std::initializer_list, but
>   aggregate initialization for the inner C-style array of std::array
>   (that's where the second set of braces comes from: One for std::array,
>   one for the inner C-style member array).

`std::array` does not have a constructor that takes an `initializer_list`. For this reason, it is treated as aggregate initialization. If it did, it would look something like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

struct test {
    int inner[3];

    test(std::initializer_list<int> list) {
        std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), inner);
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    test t{1, 2, 3};
    test t2({1, 2, 3});
    test t3 = {1, 2, 3};
    test t4 = test({1, 2, 3});
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        std::cout << t.inner[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        std::cout << t2.inner[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        std::cout << t3.inner[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        std::cout << t4.inner[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last 2 are redundant : you could use the 6 forms of array declaration on the right side of the assignment. In addition, if your compiler doesn't optimize out the copy, these versions are less efficient.

The double braces are required with initializer-list constructor, so your third line is invalid.