# why is 1 extra bracket needed for the initializer list

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have been reading a book called "C++ How To Program" by Paul and Harvey Deitel. I am stuck at page 357 because if I follow the book and try putting only **{**{ }**}** instead of **{{**{ }**}}**, I will receive an error:

> too many initializers for 'std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 3>'

Why do I need to put 1 extra set of brackets in the initializer list? For example, if I tried to put only
{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}} instead of **{**{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}**}** I will get an error.

```
 int main()
 {
    array<array<int, 2>, 3> a {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};

    for(auto const& i : a)
    {
        for(auto const& j : i)
        {
            std::cout << j << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Aggregate initialization of a structure that contains an array of structures that contain an array. Does [std::array aggregate initialization requires a confusing amount of curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150369/stdarray-aggregate-initialization-requires-a-confusing-amount-of-curly-braces) explain?

Answer (score 2):

From [`std::array`'s documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

> This container is an **aggregate type** with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array `T[N]` as its only non-static data member.

This in turn means that, we will need outer braces for the ***class type*** itself and then inner braces for the C style `T[n]` array.

Now lets apply this to your case of 2D array:

```
//                          v----------------------------> needed for inner C style array  
array<array<int, 2>, 3> a { { {1,2},{3,4},{5,6} } };
//                        ^------------------------------> needed for class type itself
```