# In C++, is it possible to initialize an array directly from another?

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax, initialization, c++14

In C++, is it possible to initialize a built-in array directly from another? As far as I know, one can only have an array and then copy/move each element from another array to it, which is some kind of assignment, not initialization.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519992/array-declaration-and-initialization-in-c11   ?

Comment: Are you concerned about inbuilt arrays a la `int n[5]`, and/or `std::array<>`s?

Comment: @TonyD I mean built-in array.

Comment: Could you please make your question more clearly ? Add some pseudo for example

Comment: @Lingxi `std::array` was introduced by C++11 as a convenient wrapper atop built-in arrays; it provides both the copy constructor and copy assignment operator, so you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: @legends2k I'm surprised that noone commented on that, but you don't have to do that manually - it's behaviour of a trivial struct (no user-defined copy operation). What actually this class does, is introduction of safe operator[] and iterator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays have neither the copy constructor nor the copy assignment operator. You can only copy elements from one array to another element by element.

Character arrays can be initialized by string literals. Or strings can be copied using standard C functions like `strcpy`, `strncpy`, `memcpy` declared in header `<cstring>`.

For other arrays you can use for example standard algorithms `std::copy`, `std::copy_if`, `std::transform` declared in header `<algorithm>`.

Otherwise you can use either standard container `std::array` or `std::vector` that allow to assign one object of the type to another object of the same type or create one object from another object.

Comment: So, the answer is basically no?

Comment: @Lingxi For built-in arrays the answer is no, The only approach is to enclose an array inside a structure (this way std::array is designed) and create an object of the structure from another object of the same type that already contains some array that should be copied.

Answer (score 6):

That is one of the new features of the [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) in `C++ 11`.

```
std::array <int, 5> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::array <int ,5> b = a;
```

The latter copies the array `a` into `b`.